# I can't seem to get my program to print the shortest word

Tags: java

Ok so my code is supposed to print out the total amount of words entered, the longest and the shortest word. I can't seem to figure out how to get it to print out the shortest word, the total and the longest work fine.

```
public void stringInput()
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int wordcount =0;
    String word ="";
    String longest = "";
    String shortest = "";
    while(! word.equals("DONE"))
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter a word or DONE to exit: ");
        word = keyboard.next();
        if(!word.equals("DONE"))
        {
            wordcount ++;
            if (word.length() < shortest.length())
               {
                shortest = word;
               }
            if (word.length() > longest.length())
            {
                longest = word;
            }
        }
   }
    System.out.println("Thank you for entering "+wordcount+" words.");
    System.out.println("Longest word :"+ longest);
    System.out.println("Shortest word :"+ shortest);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No word is shorter than `""`, so `shortest` never changes. One fix is to set `shortest` to the first word rather than `""`. Another is to change the `if` so that it sets `shortest` if the word is shorter or if `shortest`'s length is still zero.

Another possibility:

```
        if ((wordcount == 1) || (word.length() < shortest.length()))
        {
            shortest = word;
        }
```

Comment: so would i just replace "" with word?

Comment: You can fix it any of the three ways I suggested (or the way augustoccesar suggested). Replacing "" with word won't work if there are no words at all though.

Comment: I am confused why did you use wordcount if that just adds up the total amount of words entered ?

Comment: @TheCompile Sorry. Either that should be `1` or should put it before you increment `wordcount`.

Comment: Thank you so much it fixed my problem its been driving me crazy for an hour lol

Answer (score 0):

No word is going to be shorter than an empty string. You should set the shortest as `null` and check if it is the first String inputed, if so, set the shortest to it, and then, all other Strings you compare with the first one.
Like so:

```
while(! word.equals("DONE"))
{
    System.out.print("Please enter a word or DONE to exit: ");
    word = keyboard.next();
    if(!word.equals("DONE"))
    {
        if(shortest != null){
            if (word.length() < shortest.length())
            {
                shortest = word;
            }
        }else{
            shortest = word;
        }
        if (word.length() > longest.length())
        {
            longest = word;
        }
        wordcount ++;
    }
}
```

Comment: But the solution isn't simple set the shortest to null. You have to check if the string is the first one before comparing. Going to update my answer.